# Spread operator behaves differently than concat with large datasets?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It might sound like a really weird question, because it is. But I'm working on a project which processes very large datasets in Node.js (v6). We query lots of events from a database and build up an immutable in memory state. But when I use `[...state, item]` instead of `[].concat(state, item)`, I seem to be missing an item. It's not even the same one every time. Anyone has any ideas on this?

State is updated using redux (I replaced the naming because it's company code):

```
function updateItem(state, action) {
  const { a, b, c, d } = action.payload.fields;
  const obj = { type: 'TYPE', a, b, c, d };

  return [...state, obj];
}
```

The items are coming from a Node.js event emitter that is triggered by a mysql query.

Comment: How large is "very large"? This will be pretty difficult to troubleshoot without some data or code that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: So `state` is an ordinary array here? Of course the two expressions do different things depending on [`isConcatSpreadable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/isConcatSpreadable) and `iterator`, but usually they should have the same outcome indeed.

Comment: It's a regular array indeed.

Comment: We're talking 50k+ items, these being added in 20 seconds or so.